# Kotlin: how to swap character in String

Tags: kotlin

I would like to swap a string from "abcde" to "bcdea". So I wrote my code as below in Kotlin

```
var prevResult = "abcde"
var tmp = prevResult[0]

for (i in 0..prevResult.length - 2) {
    prevResult[i] = prevResult[i+1]  // Error on preveResult[i]
}

prevResult[prevResult.length-1] = tmp // Error on preveResult[prevResult.lengt-1]
```

It errors out as stated above comment line. What did I do wrong? How could I fix this and get what I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Strings in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html) just like in Java are immutable, so there is no `string.set(index, value)` (which is what `string[index] = value` is equivalent to).

To build a string from pieces you could use a `StringBuilder`, construct a `CharSequence` and use `joinToString`, operate on a plain array (`char[]`) or do `result = result + nextCharacter` (creates a new String each time -- this is the most expensive way).

Here's how you could do this with `StringBuilder`:

```
var prevResult = "abcde"
var tmp = prevResult[0]

var builder = StringBuilder()

for (i in 0..prevResult.length - 2) {
  builder.append(prevResult[i+1])
}

builder.append(tmp)  // Don't really need tmp, use prevResult[0] instead.
var result = builder.toString()
```

However, a much simpler way to achieve your goal ("bcdea" from "abcde") is to just "move" one character:

```
var result = prevResult.substring(1) + prevResult[0]
```

or using the `Sequence` methods:

```
var result = prevResult.drop(1) + prevResult.take(1)
```

Comment: Consider using `buildString` as a more concise way of building a `String`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/build-string.html

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`drop(1)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/drop.html) and [`first()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/first.html) (or [`take(1)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/take.html)) to do it in one line:

```
val str = "abcde"
val r1 = str.drop(1) + str.first()
val r2 = str.drop(1) + str.take(1)
```

As to your code, Kotlin [`String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/) is immutable and you cannot modify its characters. To achieve what you want, you can convert a `String` to `CharArray`, modify it and then make a new `String` of it:

```
val r1 = str.toCharArray().let {
    for (i in 0..it.lastIndex - 1)
        it[i] = it[i+1]
    it[it.lastIndex] = str[0] // str is unchanged
    String(it)
}
```

([`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) is used for conciseness to avoid creating more variables)

---

Also, you can write a more general version of this operation as an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) for `String`:

```
fun String.rotate(n: Int) = drop(n % length) + take(n % length)
```

Usage:

```
val str = "abcde"
val r1 = str.rotate(1)
```

Comment: I wonder what is the performance for those. In a naive implementation the version with `CharArray` must be the most mem-efficient and mem-local. On the other hand JIT may optimise the other ones away, so there is 1 allocation instead of 3.

Comment: @voddan, here's a test with the result: https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/bc508a573abfe8e8b3b3. Seems quite strange, but drop+take shows itself a little better.

Comment: hah, nobody expected `StringBuilder` to shine here :) Thanks for the tests!

Answer (score 3):

Simpler solution: Just use toMutableList() to create a MutableList of Char and then join it all together with joinToString.

Example:

Given a String input, we want to exchange characters at positions posA and posB:

```
val chars = input.toMutableList()
val temp = chars[posA]
chars[posA] = chars[posB]
chars[posB] = temp
return chars.joinToString(separator = "")
```

Comment: Making the string a Mutable List solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since Strings are immutable, you will have to copy the source string into an array, make changes to the array, then create a new string from the modified array.  Look into:

- [getChars()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getChars(int,%20int,%20char[],%20int)) to copy the string chars into an array.
- Perform your algorithm on that array, making changes to it as needed.
- Convert the modified array back into a String with [String(char[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])).